# GPIO in unprivileged LXC container

Tags: permissions, lxc, sysfs, gpio

I currently try to get GPIO-access into an unprivileged LXC application container. In future this container shall execute an application. But for now (while development) I just start a normal bash in the container:

```
sudo lxc-execute -n gpio-client -f /var/proj/gpio-client/lxc.conf -- bin/bash
```

When I do this with a privileged container (means my lxc.conf doesn't contain any UID- or GID-mapping) I can use the GPIO's.
The GPIO's can be access over files in /sys/class/gpio (following output comes from a bash within a privileged container which was started with the command above):

```
bash-4.3# cd /sys/class/gpio/
bash-4.3# ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwx---    1 gpio-cli 1001          4096 Feb 20 12:41 export
lrwxrwxrwx    1 gpio-cli 1001             0 Feb 20 12:41 gpiochip890 -> ../../devices/gpiochip2/gpio/gpiochip890
lrwxrwxrwx    1 gpio-cli 1001             0 Feb 20 12:41 gpiochip898 -> ../../devices/gpiochip1/gpio/gpiochip898
lrwxrwxrwx    1 gpio-cli 1001             0 Feb 20 12:41 gpiochip906 -> ../../devices/soc0/amba/e000a000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip906
-rwxrwx---    1 gpio-cli 1001          4096 Feb 20 12:41 unexport
```

For example I am able to export a GPIO:

```
bash-4.3# echo 898 > export
bash-4.3# ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwx---    1 gpio-cli 1001          4096 Feb 20 14:06 export
lrwxrwxrwx    1 gpio-cli 1001             0 Feb 20 14:06 gpio898 -> ../../devices/gpiochip1/gpio/gpio898
lrwxrwxrwx    1 gpio-cli 1001             0 Feb 20 12:41 gpiochip890 -> ../../devices/gpiochip2/gpio/gpiochip890
lrwxrwxrwx    1 gpio-cli 1001             0 Feb 20 12:41 gpiochip898 -> ../../devices/gpiochip1/gpio/gpiochip898
lrwxrwxrwx    1 gpio-cli 1001             0 Feb 20 12:41 gpiochip906 -> ../../devices/soc0/amba/e000a000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip906
-rwxrwx---    1 gpio-cli 1001          4096 Feb 20 12:41 unexport
```

When I print the running processes on the host with "ps -a" I can see the running bash as root:

```
      587 root       0:00 lxc-execute -n gpio-client -f /var/proj/gpio-client/lxc.conf -- bin/bash
      598 root       0:00 /init.lxc.static -- bin/bash
      615 root       0:00 bin/bash
```

But when I insert a UID- and GID-mapping into the lxc.conf (and also the subuids and subgids in /etc/subuid and /etc/subgid) I always get a "Permission denied" when I try to access /sys/class/gpio:

```
bash-4.3# cd /sys/class/
bash-4.3# ls -l
total 0
drwxrwx---    2 65534    gpio             0 Feb 20 14:11 gpio
bash-4.3# cd gpio/
bash: cd: gpio/: Permission denied
```

This is my lxc.conf:

```
# *************************************************************************
# * general configuration
# *************************************************************************

# container name
lxc.utsname = gpio-client

# *************************************************************************
# * configure networking
# *************************************************************************

lxc.network.type          =   veth
lxc.network.flags         =   up
lxc.network.link          =   local_br0
lxc.network.name          =   lxcnet0
lxc.network.hwaddr        =   4a:49:43:49:79:ac
lxc.network.ipv4          =   10.10.0.98
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway  =   10.10.0.1

# *************************************************************************
# * configure container filesystem
# *************************************************************************

# set rootfs
lxc.rootfs = /var/proj/gpio-client/rootfs

# mount needed directories from host
lxc.mount.entry=/lib                lib             none    ro,bind     0   0
lxc.mount.entry=/sys/class/gpio     sys/class/gpio  none    rw,bind     0   0
lxc.mount.entry=/sys/devices        sys/devices     none    rw,bind     0   0
lxc.mount.entry=/usr/lib            usr/lib         none    ro,bind     0   0
lxc.mount.entry=/usr/bin            usr/bin         none    ro,bind     0   0
lxc.mount.entry=/bin                bin             none    ro,bind     0   0

# *************************************************************************
# * configure privileges of container
# *************************************************************************

# map user and group ids
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/userns.conf
# comment the following out for a privileged container:
lxc.id_map = u 0 1000000 65536
lxc.id_map = g 0 1000000 65536
```

This is the running linux-system:

```
zedboard-zynq7:/var/proj/gpio-client$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 4.6.0-rt1-xilinx-v2016.3 (sebastian@ubuntu1604vm) (gcc version 6.2.0 (GCC) ) #5 SMP PREEMPT RT Fri Apr 7 13:43:09 CEST 2017
```

The system was build using Yocto for a AVNET-Zedboard (which has a Xilinx Zynq-SoC).

Does anyone have an idea or advise how to get this running or where to find the solution/information for this? I tried to get it running for a couple of hours but unfortunately I didn't managed it...

Best regards
Sebastian